# Jquery popup for images

Tags: jquery, html, popup, requirejs, lightbox

there are three or more images in a single html page and need to show same image in popup after clicking on particular image. Is there anything which I can use for this?

```
<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img1.jpg" alt="img1" width="232" height="300">
<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img2.jpg" alt="img2" width="232" height="300">
<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img3.jpg" alt="img3" width="232" height="300">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in javascript by adding an onclick function on your images

`$('.wp-image-4596').click(function(){
    $('#popupimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});`

`<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img1.jpg" alt="img1" width="232" height="300">
<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img2.jpg" alt="img2" width="232" height="300">
<img class="wp-image-4596 size-medium" src="img3.jpg" alt="img3" width="232" height="300">
<div id="popup"><!--this is your pop for example-->
    <img src='' id="popupimage">
</div>`

this will get the source of the clicked image and use it as the source for your popup image

Comment: This shows the image in a separate div, but does not pop-up a modal window and display the image inside. If your requirement is to show the image in just another separate div, then this answer suits!!

Comment: @PrashanthBR yes it does. and FYI a div can be a modal by adding the right css and attributes. That's why I added in the code "<!--this is your pop for example-->"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bootstrap modal. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537135/how-to-implement-an-image-popup-in-jquery-for-firebase) for my answer on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man use lightbox2 jQuery plugin, this have cool effects and functionality.

If you like to use more simpler plugin then you can use magnafic popup plugin.